# Como mudo a cor dos valores de indice do grafico?

Tags: javascript, html, gráfico

Preciso alterar a cor desse indice para branco
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém, não encontrei um metodo de alterar esses valores.

Aqui esta meu codigo html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Graficos</title>
</head>

<body style="background: rgb(133, 133, 133);">

    <canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>

    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("line-chart");

        var grafico = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Atendimentos por mês",
                    data: [180, 35, 86, 200, 250, 128, 10, 24, 87, 202, 27, 156],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(38,201,46,1)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(38,201,46,1)',
                    fontColor: '#fff'
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    text: "Atendimentos no Mês",
                    fontColor: '#fff'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false,
                            color: '#fff'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            color: '#fff'
                        }
                    }]
                },

            }
        });

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As cores estão sendo gerenciadas dentro do JS `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>`, você pode copiar este JS e fazer as mudanças que necessita, ao invés de utilizar a tag com o JS padrão, irá utilizar um documento dentro do seu sistema.

Comment: Mas como posso mudar pelo JS padrão?

Comment: Tu terá que copiar o documento que está dentro da URL e depois, ao invés de chamar a url, irá chamar o documento. Por exemplo, digamos que tu tenha uma árvore de pastas desta forma: `js`>`graficos`>`grafico.js`, tu vai chamar este documento desta forma: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/graficos/grafico.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alterar usando `ticks/fontColor` dentro do Axes que você quer (no caso, o Y):

```
yAxes: [{
   display: true,
   gridLines: {
       color: '#fff'
   },
    ticks: {
     fontColor: 'white' // aqui branco
    },
}]
```

Veja:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Graficos</title>
</head>

<body style="background: rgb(133, 133, 133);">

    <canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>

    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("line-chart");

        var grafico = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Atendimentos por mês",
                    data: [180, 35, 86, 200, 250, 128, 10, 24, 87, 202, 27, 156],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(38,201,46,1)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(38,201,46,1)',
                    fontColor: '#fff'
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    text: "Atendimentos no Mês",
                    fontColor: '#fff'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false,
                            color: '#fff'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            color: '#fff'
                        },
                         ticks: {
                          fontColor: 'white' // aqui branco
                         }

                    }]
                },

            }
        });

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.

Comment: E como alteraria a label acima do grafico? ("Atendimentos por mês")

Comment: Veja [aqui na documentação](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html) onde tem "legend".

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou certinho.